# override inline style for all childs inside a div

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="color:#FFFFFF !important;">

<!-- A Dynamic content comes from from third party. -->
<p style="color:red;"> This should be white instead of red. </p>
<p>Test is test. This should also be white.    </p>
<span> Check is check. This should also be white.    </span>
<!-- Dynamic Content ends -->
</div>
```

HOW do I make all the texts to be white inside the div given above. Is it possible by using any **jquery** or other similar language??

Comment: If you want it to be white - why do you set the color as red?

Comment: That is a dynamic content as I've mentioned. That code comes from third party. Above code is just a demo. The content may be of any color.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery `children()` and `css()` function to override the style , check my [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4FZF/) for the demo

Comment: Thank you. But it worked the other way. 
    $('#test p').css("color","white");
     $('#test span').css("color","white");

:-)

Comment: @MeelanLohani I use .children because you state all the DOM inside the div and not only with `p` (which is my first answer thou)

Comment: But using children did not change the    p that have inline css. Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found answer.

```
$(div p).css('color':'white');
$(div span).css('color':'white');
```

This was what I exactly wanted. It overrided the inline css of all the     p tag as well.